# java escape character replaceAll not working

Tags: java

i wanna change escape charater `\\` to `\\\` so here is my code

as is  `"{\"address\":\"{\\"area\\"}\"}"`

expected `"{\"address\":\"{\\\"area\\\"}\"}"`

```
final String s = file.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\");
```

but error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing

how can i replace `\\` to `\\\` ??

Comment: `"{\"address\":\"{\\"area\\"}\"}"` is not a valid string literal.

Comment: it doesn't helpful i wanna  \ * 3

Comment: Basically, what you're appending is backslash-equivalent to `///` (blame formatting `\\\``), which means you're going to have `//` (which is fine) followed by `/` (which this exception is raised for). You need to having a trailing character that is escaped (since `//` is an unescaped `/` and `////` is a literal `/`). In your case, `//` happens to be followed by `"`, so while it's _really ugly_, you could technically do `file.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\\"", "\\\\\\\\\\\\\"")`. Or you can follow the linked duplicate and find a better solution.

Comment: i just wanna \\  to \\\ but there is no solution...

Comment: Use replace in loop or use what i have mentioned in the answer !

Comment: Don’t use replaceAll.  There is no reason to use regular expressions here.  Just use [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)), as in `replace("\\\\", "\\\\\\")`.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc of [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) says:

> Note that backslashes ( \ ) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
> string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
> treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. **Use
> Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)** to suppress the special
> meaning of these characters, if desired.